# Create AWS Couchbase Enterprise Instance with our own Couchbase licence

Tags: amazon-ec2, couchbase

I have create multiple AWS instance running Amazon linux with Couchbase Enterprise 4.5.1. edition installed in it. I can use Couchbase AMIs to create AWS instance. But the problem in this approach is how to use Couchbase licence that was purchased by organization. I cannot go for on-fly purchase or hourly / yearly subscription for Couchbase. Could you help me with the steps that has to follow to add our own Couchbase licence?

Answer (score 0):

Given how you want to obtain/use the software, you're best off just picking the AMI you want to run on and start instances from that.  It's functionally the same.